# Your current user or role does not have access to Kubernetes objects on this EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, eksctl

Don't know if this is an error from AWS or something. I created an IAM user and gave it full admin policies. I then used this user to create an EKS cluster using the `eksctl` CLI but when I logging to AWS console with the **root user** I got the below error while trying to access the cluster nodes.

***Your current user or role does not have access to Kubernetes objects on this EKS cluster
This may be due to the current user or role not having Kubernetes RBAC permissions to describe cluster resources or not having an entry in the cluster’s auth config map.***

I have these questions

1. Does not the root user have full access to view every resource from the console?
2. If the above is true, does it mean when I create a resource from the CLI I must login with the same user to view it?
3. Or is there way I could attach policies to the root user? Didn't see anything like in the console.

AWS itself does not recommend creating access keys for root user and using it for programmable access, so I'm so confused right now. Someone help

All questions I have seen so far and the link to the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting_iam.html#security-iam-troubleshoot-cannot-view-nodes-or-workloads) are talking about a user or role created in the AWS IAM and not the root user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue today, and solved it by combining answers here. The aws-auth config after it worked looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::671177010163:role/eksctl-manu-eks-new2-nodegroup-ng-NodeInstanceRole-1NYUHVMYFP2TK
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  mapUsers: "- groups: \n  - system:masters\n  userarn: arn:aws:iam::671177010163:root\n"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-13T11:03:30Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "11362"
  uid: ac36a1d9-76bc-40dc-95f0-b1e7934357
```

Comment: I combined my configmap/aws-auth - https://pastebin.com/yqnL3v2y - but it still shows an Error in “Health issues” and a warning still exist

Comment: This is the most complete answer, and solves the problem.

Answer (score 44):

If you're logged in with the root user and get this error, run the below command to edit the `aws-auth` configMap:

```
kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system
```

Then go down to `mapUsers` and add the following (replace `[account_id]` with your Account ID)

```
mapUsers: |
  - userarn: arn:aws:iam::[account_id]:root
    groups:
    - system:masters
```

Comment: My EKS cluster is created by a Cloudformation template, not through any CLI and I am getting the exact same issue. Where do I run the command `kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system` ?

Comment: Worth mentioning that you probably won't have the "mapUsers" entry, so you'll need to add it in the same identation level as "mapRoles".

Comment: When I try run the kubectl command I got Error from server (Forbidden): configmaps "aws-auth" is forbidden: User "arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/terraform/botocore-session-17114521234" cannot get resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"

This started happening since I switched from manually creating EKS resources in terraform to using a module "eks"

Answer (score 10):

From what I've understood, EKS manages user and role permissions through a ConfigMap called `aws-auth` that resides in the `kube-system` namespace. So despite being logged in with an AWS user with full administrator access to all services, EKS will still limit your access in the console as it can't find the user or role in its authentication configuration.

When I had this issue, I solved it by editing the aws-auth configmap by adding  the following under mapRoles:

```
- "groups":
  - "system:masters"
  "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<aws-role-name>"
  "username": "<aws-username>"
```

Where `aws-role-name` is the role name shown when logged into the aws console in the top right corner.

I guess this could also done with the `eksctl`-utility as documented here: https://eksctl.io/usage/iam-identity-mappings/

So, maybe something like:

`eksctl create iamidentitymapping --cluster  <clusterName> --region=<region> --arn arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<aws-role-name> --group system:masters --username <aws-username>`

Using `eksctl` is probably a better way of doing it, though I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I used the second option, I could see the configmap but it didn't solve the root user permission error

Comment: My EKS cluster is created by a Cloudformation template, not through any CLI and I am getting the exact same issue. Where do I run the command to edit aws-auth ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like IAM user that you're signed into the AWS Management Console with (or role that you switched to after signing in) doesn't have the necessary permissions.

Here is pure AWS way to solve this (no manually config editing). Recommended by AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/view-kubernetes-resources.html#view-kubernetes-resources-permissions

1. Create IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:ListFargateProfiles",
                "eks:DescribeNodegroup",
                "eks:ListNodegroups",
                "eks:ListUpdates",
                "eks:AccessKubernetesApi",
                "eks:ListAddons",
                "eks:DescribeCluster",
                "eks:DescribeAddonVersions",
                "eks:ListClusters",
                "eks:ListIdentityProviderConfigs",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameter",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:111122223333:parameter/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create IAM role and attach policy to role. Attach policy to IAM user.
3. Create a Kubernetes rolebinding or clusterrolebinding. To view all K8s resources in EKS run

```
kubectl apply -f https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/docs/eks-console-full-access.yaml
```

Note that this config uses group name `eks-console-dashboard-full-access-group` (you'll use it further).

4. Add a mapping for a role (from the step 1).

```
eksctl create iamidentitymapping \
    --cluster my-cluster \
    --region=region-code \
    --arn arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/my-console-viewer-role \
    --group eks-console-dashboard-full-access-group \
    --no-duplicate-arns
```

Replace here cluster name, region and role ARN.

5. Add a mapping for a user (look step 1).

```
eksctl create iamidentitymapping \
    --cluster my-cluster \
    --region=region-code \
    --arn arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/my-user \
    --group eks-console-dashboard-full-access-group \
    --no-duplicate-arns
```

That all. You may view the mappings in the ConfigMap now:

```
eksctl get iamidentitymapping --cluster my-cluster --region=region-code
```

You have to see both role and user in mapping.

After that you'll be able to see K8s resources in AWS Management console.

Answer (score 2):

The IAM user you use to log into the EKS console has to be given explicit permissions, via Kubernetes Role-based access control (RBAC), to access EKS resources even if the IAM user has "root" privileges.

To fix this issue, make sure you have kubectl installed on your system.

```
kubectl version
```

If you don't have kubectl installed on your system, you can install it by using [brew](https://brew.sh/) on macOS:

```
brew install kubectl
```

Otherwise, follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html) for your operating system i.e. Linux, .

Next step is to use the AWS CLI to authenticate kubectl:

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name MyEksCluster --region us-west-2 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::[accountNumber]:role/[EksMastersRole]
```

> If you used the standard CDK constructs to deploy your EKS cluster, this command will be displayed in the CDK output for you to copy. Otherwise, you can find the parts you need (i.e. **name**, **region**, **role-arn**) to construct it by logging into the EKS console.

The final step is to edit your aws-auth config map, to do so:

```
kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system
```

And update the `mapUsers` section as follows.

```yaml
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::[accountId]:user/[username]
      groups:
      - system:masters
```

> You can find your `userarn` by logging into the AWS console then go to **Users** > **[username]**. You will find it under the Summary section.

Now you can navigate to the EKS and it should be working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

## grant RBAC permission for IAM principle (allow it to view eks)

### Step One

#### method 1: aws cli

- create policy to include the necessary permissions for a principal to view Kubernetes resources for all clusters in your account.
  replace the following `111122223333` with your `aws account id`

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:ListFargateProfiles",
                "eks:DescribeNodegroup",
                "eks:ListNodegroups",
                "eks:ListUpdates",
                "eks:AccessKubernetesApi",
                "eks:ListAddons",
                "eks:DescribeCluster",
                "eks:DescribeAddonVersions",
                "eks:ListClusters",
                "eks:ListIdentityProviderConfigs",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameter",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:111122223333:parameter/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- create EKS connector IAM role with its policy.
  AmazonEKSConnectorAgentRole:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

AmazonEKSConnectorAgentPolicy:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SsmControlChannel",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:eks:*:*:cluster/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ssmDataplaneOperations",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Create the Amazon EKS Connector agent role using the trust policy and policy you created in the previous list items.

```js
aws iam create-role \
     --role-name AmazonEKSConnectorAgentRole \
     --assume-role-policy-document file://eks-connector-agent-trust-policy.json
```

- Attach the policy to your Amazon EKS Connector agent role.

```js
aws iam put-role-policy \
     --role-name AmazonEKSConnectorAgentRole \
     --policy-name AmazonEKSConnectorAgentPolicy \
     --policy-document file://eks-connector-agent-policy.json
```

#### method 2: terraform

```js
//https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/view-kubernetes-resources.html#view-kubernetes-resources-permissions
//create EKSViewResourcesPolicy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "eks_view_resources_policy" {
  name        = "EKSViewResourcesPolicy"
  description = "Policy to allow a principal to view Kubernetes resources for all clusters in the account"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "eks:ListFargateProfiles",
          "eks:DescribeNodegroup",
          "eks:ListNodegroups",
          "eks:ListUpdates",
          "eks:AccessKubernetesApi",
          "eks:ListAddons",
          "eks:DescribeCluster",
          "eks:DescribeAddonVersions",
          "eks:ListClusters",
          "eks:ListIdentityProviderConfigs",
          "iam:ListRoles"
        ]
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Action   = "ssm:GetParameter"
        Resource = "arn:aws:ssm:*:${var.aws_account_id}:parameter/*"
      }
    ]
  })
}


//https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/connector_IAM_role.html
// create AmazonEKSConnectorAgentRole and AmazonEKSConnectorAgentPolicy
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_connector_agent_role" {
  name = "AmazonEKSConnectorAgentRole"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "ssm.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "eks_connector_agent_policy" {
  name = "AmazonEKSConnectorAgentPolicy"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "SsmControlChannel"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel"
        ]
        Resource = "arn:aws:eks:*:*:cluster/*"
      },
      {
        Sid    = "ssmDataplaneOperations"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
          "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel",
          "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel"
        ]
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_cluster_policy_attachment" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_connector_agent_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_connector_agent_custom_policy_attachment" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.eks_connector_agent_policy.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_connector_agent_role.name
}
```

### Step Two

- Once you create EKS cluster, update the kubeconfig

```js
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region <your region name> --name <your eks cluster name>
```

- Create a Kubernetes rolebinding or clusterrolebinding that is bound to a Kubernetes role or clusterrole that has the necessary permissions to view the Kubernetes resources.
  -- View Kubernetes resources in all namespaces

```js
kubectl apply -f https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/docs/eks-console-full-access.yaml
```

-- View Kubernetes resources in a specific namespace

```js
kubectl apply -f https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/docs/eks-console-restricted-access.yaml
```

or using customized by updating the downloaed file

```js
curl -O https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/docs/eks-console-full-access.yaml

kubectl apply -f rbac.yaml
```

rbac.yaml:

```js
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: reader
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: reader
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

### Step Three

- Map the IAM principal to the Kubernetes user or group in the aws-auth ConfigMap

```js
kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth
```

add:

```js
mapUsers: |
  - groups:
    - reader
    userarn: arn:aws:iam::1111111111:user/admin
    username: admin
mapRoles: |
  - groups:
    - reader
    rolearn: arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/AmazonEKSConnectorAgentRole
    username: AmazonEKSConnectorAgentRole
```

- references:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/view-kubernetes-resources.html#view-kubernetes-resources-permissions

Comment: This is a great detailed answer and helped me thanks.  The issue I had in particular was because I had a user from one AWS account that had switched roles (assuming a role) in another AWS account.  I added the rolearn of the assumed role with the groups `system:master` 
 ` - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/DevelopAccountAccessRole
      groups:
      - system:masters
`

Comment: Great answer - but I still dont understand how a root user can't view pods in EKS lmao.  IT's root for god sake

Comment: In AWS's Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS), permissions to interact with the Kubernetes API, including the ability to view pods, are governed by Kubernetes' own Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) system, separate from AWS IAM. When you create an EKS cluster, AWS associates the IAM identity of the user creating the cluster with the system:masters group in Kubernetes, granting that IAM user administrative permissions within the cluster. Other IAM users and roles are not automatically granted permissions within the cluster.

Comment: @AdamHughes The concept of a "root" user doesn't directly translate into the Kubernetes RBAC model. Even if you're logged in with an IAM user that has administrative permissions in your AWS account, you won't necessarily have permissions within an EKS cluster unless those permissions have been explicitly granted.

Answer (score 0):

For people using terraform you can use the terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws module to create you cluster:
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest?tab=inputs

then use the arguments `manage_aws_auth_configmap` and `aws_auth_users` like:

```
module "eks_cluster" {
source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
...
manage_aws_auth_configmap = true
aws_auth_users            = ["arn:aws:iam::1111111111:root"]
...
}
```